# Istio Traffic Routing deny by match prefix

Tags: istio

Is there a way to deny traffic to a specific prefix so only internal traffic is allowed?

Example from [here](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#request-routing)

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
name: bookinfo
spec:
hosts:
    - bookinfo.com
gateways:
- bookinfo-gateway
http:
- match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /v2  # <---- route all traffic to /v2*
    route:
    ...
- match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /v2/internal  # <---- but deny all traffic to /v2/internal*
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to achieve this:

1. Direct the traffic intended to /v2/internal* to 127.0.0.1
2. Use Policy blacklist adapter to deny requests to /v2/internal*, see [this](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/#attribute-based-whitelists-or-blacklists). Use `request.path` [attribute](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/attribute-vocabulary/) as the value of the listentry.